# The ++ operator is not functioning in JS when I tries to add one to it

Tags: javascript

I know that the question has been asked before. But it is different. So I have a score variable and I increase by 1 when a user answers a question. It works at first, and it stops working. I don't think it's a postfix or prefix.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Math 24
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Play this game by typing a expression that = 24. Do not type the result or the equal sign
</h1>
<p id="d">
</p>

<p id="score">
Your score: 0
</p>
<label for="Enter your expression">
Enter your expression
</label>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="myResult()">
Check
</button>
<p id="error">
</p>
<button onclick="new_puzzle()">
New Challenge
</button>
<p>
Can't solve the puzzle?
</p>
<button onclick="skip()">
Skip This One
</button>
<script>
function myResult(){
var score = 0;
    var getInputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
if(getInputValue.includes(num1, num2, num3, num4) == true){
parseInt(getInputValue);
eval(getInputValue);
}
if(eval(getInputValue) == 24){
score++;
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Great Job! You got it!';
document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Your score: ' + score;
}

else if(getInputValue === ""){
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Empty field are not allowed';
}

    else{
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Keep trying';
}


    }
</script>
        <script>
var num1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var num2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var num3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var num4 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
String(num1, num2, num3, num4);
document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = "Your numbers are:" + num1 + ' ' + num2 + ' ' + num3 + ' ' + num4;
</script>
<script>
function new_puzzle(){
var num1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var num2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var num3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var num4 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
String(num1, num2, num3, num4);
document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = "Your numbers are:" + num1 + ' ' + num2 + ' ' + num3 + ' ' + num4;

document.getElementById('error').style.display === "none";
}
</script>
<script>
function skip(){
var num1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var num2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var num3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
var num4 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
String(num1, num2, num3, num4);
document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = "Your numbers are:" + num1 + ' ' + num2 + ' ' + num3 + ' ' + num4;

document.getElementById('error').style.display === "none";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The score should increase by one whenever a question is answered correctly.

Comment: Every time my result() is click ```var score``` changes back to 0

Comment: Sorry, I'm blind. I don't see. If you want, feel free to edit my post!

Comment: I see you already have your answer, but you should know that `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)` rounds up no matter what, so your chances of zero are slim, but still possible if `Math.random()` returns zero, which it can. `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and .9 repeating, never 1. What numbers do you really want?

Comment: @StackSlave, it would never return 0. Math.ceil() rounds up not down.

Comment: `console.log(Math.ceil(0));` Notice that you get `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the button is clicked, the myResult function is called which **redefines score as 0**. You can try making score a global variable by taking the declaration out of the function.